# Unknown META specification, cannot validate. [Spec v1.0.1]

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-extensions

## PGXN upload issue:

I am trying to uplaod this distribution pcakage into PGXN, this is the new version my_extension 1.0.1. THe previous extension: https://pgxn.org/dist/my_extension/1.0.0/

Getting this error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFuOq.png)

The extension code is on my github: https://github.com/IshaanAdarsh/Postgres-extension-tutorial/tree/main/Code/my_extension

The regression tests work and everything else works fine.

The Code for the META.json file is given below
I have checked on mutiple sites, this is valid JSON.
Could you help me figure out what is the problem with my code:

```json
{
  "name": "my_extension",
  "abstract": "A Basic PostgreSQL extension",
  "description": "my_extension is a PostgreSQL extension that provides additional functionality for data management and operations.",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "maintainer": [
    "Ishaan Adarsh <ishaanad9@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "license": "postgresql",
  "provides": {
    "my_extension": {
      "file": "my_extension--1.0.1.sql",
      "docfile": "doc/my_extension.md",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },
  "generated_by": "Ishaan Adarsh",
  "meta-spec": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "url": "https://pgxn.org/meta/spec.txt"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `meta-spec` must be version `1.0.0`.  That's referring to the version of the JSON specification, NOT your module version.  `1.0.0` is the only spec that exists.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.
I have been stuck on this for like an hour now.